# In $9$-gons are two distinct diagonals, such that the two lines consisting those diagonals are parallel or intersect in less than $7^{\circ}$

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Prove that in all convex $9$-gons there are two distinct diagonals, such that the two lines consisting those diagonals are either parallel or intersect in an angle less than $7^{\circ}$.Is there a simple way?

Answer (score 1):

There are $27$ diagonals. For each such diagonal $d_i$,where $i$ goes from $0$ to $27$, let $\theta_i$ be the angle the diagonal $d_i$ makes with the positive $x$-axis.

Note that $7\cdot 26=182\gt 180$. Divide the interval from $0$ to $180$ into $26$ equal subintervals. They all have length $\frac{180}{26}\lt 7$.

Since there are $27$ diagonals, by the Pigeonhole Principle there is an interval that contains two of the $\theta_i$, say $\theta_j$ and $\theta_k$. Then the angle between $d_j$ and $d_k$ is $0$, or if positive is less than $\frac{180}{26}$, which is less than $7$.